# reading the attributes of xml file using xmlnode

Tags: c#, xmldocument

I am trying to reading the attributes using xml node..But I am unable to read it. I am doing something but i couldn't figure it out. My xml file looks like this..
[image: Xml File]

and I am trying to read InterfaceRequestID and InterfaceName, here is my code..

```
if (fPortalGuid != string.Empty)
                {
                    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://cramapp-dt-02s.cable.comcast.com:8158/restfulqueryservice/queryservice/getrequestdetails?api_key=hiding key&request_id=33ebc6e9-9def-4f39-adf9-bba2edef3b54") as HttpWebRequest;
                    request.Method = "POST";

                    using (Stream stm = request.GetRequestStream())
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter stmw = new StreamWriter(stm))
                        {
                            stmw.Write(soap);
                        }
                    }
                    // Get response  
                    using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
                    {
                        // Get the response stream  
                        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                        // Console application output  
                        string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                        xmlDoc.LoadXml(result);
                        XmlNodeList radiusdns_nodelist;
                        XmlNodeList request_nodelist;
                        XmlNodeList fqdn_nodelist;
                        radiusdns_nodelist = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/RADIUSDNSQueryResponsePayload");
                        request_nodelist = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/RADIUSDNSQueryResponsePayload/request");
                        fqdn_nodelist = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/RADIUSDNSQueryResponsePayload/request/fqdn");
                        string strInterfaceID = string.Empty, strInterfaceName = string.Empty;
                        if (radiusdns_nodelist.Count > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (XmlNode main_node in radiusdns_nodelist[0].ChildNodes)
                            {
                                strInterfaceID = main_node.Attributes["InterfaceRequestID"].Value;
                                strInterfaceName = main_node.Attributes["InterfaceName"].Value;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I AM unable to get the attributes. WHat I am doing wrong?

Comment: what is the error or problem you were having?

Comment: its like object reference not set to instance of an object

Comment: I got it thanks any way. I changed my code foreach (XmlNode main_node in radiusdns_nodelist[0].ChildNodes)
 to         foreach (XmlNode main_node in radiusdns_nodelist) now its working fine

Comment: @Tronics Glad I saw your comment before I posted that as an answer. Would have opened myself to ridicule. :(